# List of items using Xpath and Selenium

Tags: c#, facebook, selenium

Hello i'm trying to fetch all friends connected within Facebook using Xpath and Selenium the problem is when i try to locate all the friends it return an Empty List.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;



namespace Automation
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            using (IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver())
            {
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://mbasic.facebook.com");

                IWebElement username = driver.FindElement(By.Name("email"));
                username.SendKeys("email");

                IWebElement password = driver.FindElement(By.Name("pass"));
                password.SendKeys("password");

                IWebElement submit = driver.FindElement(By.Name("login"));
                submit.Submit();


                var waitHomePage = new WebDriverWait(driver,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                waitHomePage.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.PartialLinkText("Chat")));

                IWebElement chat = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='header']/div/a[6]"));
                //driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
                chat.Click();

                IList<IWebElement> friends = chat.FindElements(By.ClassName("m br bs"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Friends.Count return 0 .

Here is the HTML of the friends chat list

```html
<div class="bo bp bq">
<table class="m br bs">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="t bt">
<a class="bu" href="/messages/read/?fbid=100002640428096&click_type=buddylist#fua">Friend Name</a>
</td>
<td class="n bv">
<img class="bw bx s" src="https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v3/yo/r/DbsprgIuYE0.png" width="7" height="14"/>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<table class="m br bs">
<table class="m br bs">
<table class="m br bs">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see you have several mistakes in your code (and the `HTML` you provided is not complete and without any information in it).

I think you try to search for friends via

```
IList<IWebElement> friends = chat.FindElements(By.ClassName("m br bs"));
```

but in this case you are using the `chat` object which referes to an `a` tag, see:

```
IWebElement chat = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='header']/div/a[6]"));
```

so i would use `driver` instead of `chat` object (because I don't know what `chat` returns in your case).

Furthermore you are trying to estimate the number of friends by searching for a `ClassName` which in your `HTML` sample doesn't contain any information (empty table). I tried to look it up myself and the difficulty is that FB do not use any unquie `IDs` for their tables. In my browser the friendlist looks something like this:

```
<table class="l bs bt">
  <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td class="s bu">
        <a class="bv" href="/messages/read/fbid=111&amp;click_type=buddylist#fua">Someuser1</a>
    </td>
       <td class="m bw"><img src="https://blabla" width="7" height="14"class="bx by r" /></td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

It seems that FB uses for each contact a `href` tag with `click_type=buddylist` ... so I tried to use this information to find the user with xpath:

```
.//*[contains(@href,'buddylist')]
```

so you could to read the userlist with

```
IList<IWebElement> friends = driver.FindElements(By.XPath(".//*[contains(@href,'buddylist')]"));
```

It works for me. Hope I could help you or give you at least a hint...

Comment: It worked for me but the Xpath expression for getting the friends list should be like this .//a[@class='bu'][contains(@href,'buddylist')] :)